# Group theory: Intuition as to what a group is

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, intuition

In group theory the group is an algebraic structure consisting of a set which has elements associated with definite finitiary operations. Can an intuitive explanation be provided as to what this means.

Comment: I would say the intuition will come when you work with groups enough. Not sure I have a strong intuition about it. yet :-).